# django database emptied when I create a new git branch on my project

Tags: django, git, sqlite, git-branch

Whilst I am working on my django project (which has a single app), I wanted to create a new git branch so I can test a new design feature, however when I am on the new branch I cannot seem to find any of my previously populated data in my database (I am using sqlite3)....why could that be the case an how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check the database file into git? If you want to share the data between dev branches, then you might want to store it somewhere else (or commit it..)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean? store it where exactly? as in it is tracked by git

Comment: sqlite is file-db. So it's just a single file somewhere on your drive. So if it is tracked by git and does not exist in another branch/is empty at another branch - so that's why. Store it somewhere outside project folder or sync this file between branches.

Comment: If you want to share it between branches you'll either need to commit it before branching, or store it outside your source tree as any other file.

Comment: ok, thanks for the replies, I want to share it between branches and I did commit it, it is included in the last commit that I branch from....still It is empty...I am missing something